# Window add event listener load not working with text/babel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

Whenever I set the script type to text/babel or text/jsx, the document and window event listeners stop working, does anyone know why this happens and how could it be fixed?, thanks

If there is no solution is there any alternative to use babel and window listener together?

This is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>

        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="dos.js" type="text/jsx"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is the js code:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    console.log('hi')
})
```

Comment: Hi ! Do you mean that you have some other code and that just the event listener part doesn't work or the whole block isn't working ?
In the 2nd case it could be that you just don't have the babel development package on your page

Comment: Hi ! Could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: I have the babel.min.js file imported

Comment: React uses a [virtual DOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-internals.html#:~:text=The%20virtual%20DOM%20(VDOM)%20is,This%20process%20is%20called%20reconciliation.&text=They%20may%20also%20be%20considered,virtual%20DOM%E2%80%9D%20implementation%20in%20React.), thus the DOM events will not work the same way, you should handle events at the component level, using [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) for example